# Filtering querysets by attribute, using method params

Tags: python, django

I'd like to find an elegant way to create methods based on queryset whose result changes according to a parameter.

I have a MyEvent class, and I want to retrieve elements, either all of them, either the uncancelled ones, either the cancelled ones.
I used 3 different methods for this but I'd like to simplify this. I found another way to do it in a single method, but I'm still not convinced myself it's the cleanest way to do. What do you think of this? Any better idea?

```
@classmethod
def get_events(cls, my_filter=None):

    # Some stuff happens here.

    events = MyEvent.objects.filter(... # some filter here)

    if my_filter is None:
        return events
    elif my_filter == "cancelled":
        return events.filter(is_cancelled=True)
    elif my_filter == "uncancelled":
        return events.filter(is_cancelled=False)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown filter value")
```

I suppose here that I must call get_events() method in views.py, so I could use a manager but it would be the same problem.

Comment: Why are you not doing this in a ModelManager? (ps: `filter` is a built-in, comparisons with None should be done with `is`, and "uncancelled" is not a word so it doesn't make sense to bless it as part of an interface..)

Comment: I could but I can't see how it would help in that case, if we take as an hypothesis that in view.py, I have to call the `get_events()` method. (thanks for `==` correction). BTW, I updated some code to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people would expect to see this kind of code in a ModelManager. You're not required to do so, but it will make your code more surprising for other people who know Django.

Interfaces that require that you specify a negative is usually confusing. Eg. in the admin for your `MyEvent` objects you will have a is_cancelled column with red minuses.  That tends to make people uncomfortable ;-)  You can remedy that in your interface though by naming your parameters appropriately:

```
@classmethod
def get_events(cls, active=None):
    # active should be True or False if specified

    # Some stuff happens here.
    events = cls.objects.filter(... # some filter here)  # note: using cls

    if active is None:
        return events

    return events.filter(is_cancelled=not active)
```

it makes the logic a bit shorter/simpler too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's definitely cleaner this way :)